# How to create wipe transition

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

I want to create animation where first image wipe from left to right then second image appear from left to right?

Like when the first image in done with the animation completely wiped from the screen then second image start appearing from left to right on the screen and after some time, the second image wiped from the screen completely and image 1 appears on screen from left to right.

Infinite process

Jsbin created

used property

```
webkit-mask-image
webkit-mask-size
webkit-animation
```

> https://jsbin.com/koqaxesejo/edit?html,css,output

Not able to understand what I am doing wrong over here?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://jsbin.com/sejevudoda/1/edit?html,css,output)?

Comment: yes something like this but image should be visible for some second then start wiping out @Harry

Comment: Like [this](https://jsbin.com/wocosofeke/edit?html,css,output)? Or you need more delay?